Invalid plugin.yml, Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header
I ran into a problem with Minecraft server. When I want to install some new plug, and it doesn’t matter which one, the following error occurs at startup:
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:186) ~[purpur-api-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:159) ~[purpur-api-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_18_R2.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:418) ~[purpur-1.18.2.jar:git-Purpur-1632]
at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:323) ~[purpur-1.18.2.jar:git-Purpur-1632]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1180) ~[purpur-1.18.2.jar:git-Purpur-1632]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$1(MinecraftServer.java:321) ~[purpur-1.18.2.jar:git-Purpur-1632]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1598) ~[?:?]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1492) ~[?:?]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1315) ~[?:?]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1277) ~[?:?]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709) ~[?:?]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243) ~[?:?]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172) ~[?:?]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347) ~[?:?]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:318) ~[?:?]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:284) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:174) ~[purpur-api-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
6 more

Server version: Purpur 1.18.2 Java17
Tried to change encoding

To be sure, the plugin.yml is well a simpple text file that can be opened with bloc note ?

The error happens when the server tries to read plugin.yml, but cannot because the zip file (probably the plugin jar itself) is corrupted.

What plugins are they and where do you get them from? Also, running a Purpur server is completely unnecessary unless there’s some setting that you absolutely can’t go without and can’t be changed already or done with API. Run Paper at most
